# How can I read a matrix with ipywidgets?

Tags: ipywidgets

I want to develop an interactive ipywidget; here I want to read the input as a matrix and compare it with another matrix I saved. How can I read a matrix?

Answer (score 0):

I established an answer in an textarea.

widgets.Textarea(
    description='Matrix:',

)

Now I want to read from this textarea a matrix. How is it possible?